# Powershell script to convert excel files to csv files with card numbers with 16 digits

Tags: powershell

I have this excel sheets and I want to have the same format for csv files. Could some one help me with a automation script please (to convert multiple excel sheets to csv files)??

I tried this script, but the 16th digit of the card number is turning to be zero as excel can read only 15 digits right. Can we modify this code to convert multiple excel sheets to csv files?

Could someone help me with this.

## Convert Excel file to CSV

```
$xlCSV=6
$Excelfilename = “C:\Temp\file.xlsx”
$CSVfilename = “C:\Temp\file.csv”
$Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $False
$Excel.displayalerts=$False
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFileName)
$Workbook.SaveAs($CSVfilename,$xlCSV)
```

$Excel.Quit()
If(ps excel){kill -name excel}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel is really particular in its handling of CSV files..
Although the 16 digit numbers are written out in full when using the `SaveAs` method, if you re-open it by double-clicking the csv file, Excel screws up these numbers by converting them to numeric values instead of strings.

In order to force Excel to **NOT** interpret these values and simply regard them as strings, you need to adjust the values in the csv file afterwards, by prefixing them with a TAB character.

<sup>(this will make the file useless for other applications..)</sup>

Of course, you **need to know** the correct column header to do this.

Let's assume your Excel file looks like this:

[image: example]

As you can see, the value we need to adjust is stored in column **Number**

To output csv files on which you can double-click so they are opened in Excel, the code below would do that for you:

```
$xlCSV      = 6
$Excelfiles = 'D:\test.xlsx', 'D:\test2.xlsx'  # an array of files to convert
$ColumnName = 'Number'                         # example, you need to know the column name

# create an Excel COM object
$Excel               = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible       = $False
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False

foreach ($fileName in $Excelfiles) {
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($fileName)
    # use the same file name, but change the extension to .csv for output
    $CSVfile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($fileName, 'csv')
    # have Excel save the csv file
    $Workbook.SaveAs($CSVfile, $xlCSV)
    $Workbook.Close($false)
}

# close excel and clean up the used COM objects
$Excel.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

# now import the csv files just created and update the card number
# column by prefixing the value with a TAB character ("`t").
# this will effectively force Excel NOT to interpret the value as numeric.
# you better not do this inside the same loop, because Excel keeps a lock
# on outputted csv files there.
foreach ($fileName in $Excelfiles) {
    # use the same file name, but change the extension to .csv for output
    $CSVfile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($fileName, 'csv')

    # the '-UseCulture' switch makes sure the same delimiter character is used
    $csv = Import-Csv -Path $CSVfile -UseCulture
    foreach ($item in $csv) { $item.$ColumnName = "`t" + $item.$ColumnName }
    # re-save the csv file with updates values
    $csv | Export-Csv -Path $CSVfile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Theo, Amazing. It works like a charm. Thank you so much.

Comment: Theo, 

$Excelfiles = 'D:\test.xlsx', 'D:\test2.xlsx' 
         
            Is there a way to give this path so that it can access all the files in the folder. I have 30-40 files and giving path individually would be a challenge. Please comment on it

Comment: @dharma That's really easy to do: `$Excelfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path '<THE FOLDERPATH>' -Filter '*.xlsx' -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`

Comment: you are Super. Thank you from bottom of my heart. You did it. Great job helping me fix the problem. 
Thanks again